# Parameters on Runnable

Tags: java, android, parameters, runnable

I'm trying to pass the "entityFinal" to the **run()** method but since it's a runnable i can't have any parameters.

The "responseView.setText" on the **runOnUiThread** is commented because my android studio is always printing that my responseView is null, and i can't see why it is, since i'm using the View on the xml correctly.

Could someone give me a hint here? i tested a lot things, asyncTask, multi threads, but this is the only way that i had this "almost" working.

Thank you on advance.

**xml :**

```
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Blank"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
```

**Java file code :**

```
 final TextView responseView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                   new Thread(){
                       public void run(){
                           try{
                             HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                             final HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                             final String entityFinal = entity.getContent().toString();
                           }catch(IOException e){
                               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                           }
                           activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   //responseView.setText(entityFinal);
                                   System.out.println(responseView);
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   }.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case, moving

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
       //responseView.setText(entityFinal);
       System.out.println(responseView);
    }
);
```

into the `try` block should be enough. In general you can always a   class, that implements Runnable with a constructor that takes an arbitrary number/type of paramters. For instance

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

     private final String mString;
     public MyRunnable(String string) {
          mString = string;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() { 
         System.out.println(mString);
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this solved some errors, but now i can't find out why my "textView" is null when i use it. When i first create it, it has the widget.TextView correct, but when i use it to set the value from the "entityFinal" the textView is null.

Comment: The why is because you probably forgot to initialize it. You should always check against null object

Comment: Found the problem, i was initializing it wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           System.out.println(responseView);
        }
    }).start();
```